# Repeating Traffic Light Sequence

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have written the code below which should do a traffic light sequence but the setInterval and setTimeout do not seem to be working as I expected them to.
What I want to do is do a set repeating time for each function that changes the colour of the light.

```js
 setInterval(function multipleFunction() {
   setInterval(trafficOne, 1000);
   setTimeout(setInterval(trafficTwo, 1000), 1000);
   setTimeout(setInterval(trafficThree, 1000), 2000);
   setTimeout(setInterval(trafficFour, 1000), 3000);
 }, 4000)


 function trafficOne() {
   document.getElementById('circle1').style.backgroundColor = 'red'
   document.getElementById('circle2').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
 }

 function trafficTwo() {
   document.getElementById('circle1').style.backgroundColor = 'black'
   document.getElementById('circle2').style.backgroundColor = 'black'
   document.getElementById('circle3').style.backgroundColor = 'green'
 }

 function trafficThree() {
   document.getElementById('circle1').style.backgroundColor = 'black'
   document.getElementById('circle2').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
   document.getElementById('circle3').style.backgroundColor = 'black'
 }

 function trafficFour() {
   document.getElementById('circle1').style.backgroundColor = 'red'
   document.getElementById('circle2').style.backgroundColor = 'black'
   document.getElementById('circle3').style.backgroundColor = 'black'
 }
```

```css
#container {
  width: 80px;
  height: 230px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
}
#container2 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 180px;
  border-style: solid;
  background: black;
  margin: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
}
#circle1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
#circle2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: black;
}
#circle3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button id="change" onClick="multipleFunction()">Start traffic</button>
  <div id="container2">
    <div id="circle1"></div>
    <div id="circle2"></div>
    <div id="circle3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually you try to run a function called multipleFunction() but this is not in your code

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear, and the code pasted in the solution is horribly trying to create intervals for your functions in a repeated way. Please explain in detail what you are trying to achieve so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define you functions well.

Try this one and try to unserdstand whats going on. If you need help just ask :)

EDIT: Add some comments, hope it helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  #container{
   width:80px;
   height:230px;
   border-style:solid;
   padding:10px;
   margin:10px;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color:black;
  }

  #container2{
   width:60px;
   height:180px;
   border-style: solid ;
   background:black;

   margin:10px;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: black;
  }

  #circle1 {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px; 
   border-radius: 25px;
   background: red;
   margin:5px;
  }
  #circle2 {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   margin:5px;
   border-radius: 25px;
   background: black;
  }
  #circle3 {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   margin:5px;
   border-radius: 25px;
   background: black;
  }
 </style>
 <script>
  // init state of timer, no timer set
  var timer = null;
  // function to start and stop the traffic light
  function toggle(){
   // test if a timer is set and running
   if(timer != null){
    // the timer is running --> stop that timer
    clearInterval(timer);
    // reset the timer
    timer = null;
    // set the traffic light to an inital state
    document.getElementById('circle1').style.backgroundColor='red';
    document.getElementById('circle2').style.backgroundColor='black';
    document.getElementById('circle3').style.backgroundColor='black';
   }else{
    // no timer is running --> start the first step
    trafficOne();
   }
  }

   function trafficOne() {
   // set the light of this state
   document.getElementById('circle1').style.backgroundColor='red';
   document.getElementById('circle2').style.backgroundColor='yellow';
   document.getElementById('circle3').style.backgroundColor='black';

   // set a timeout of 1s, if it is over start the next function
   timer = window.setTimeout(trafficTwo, 1000);
  }

   function trafficTwo() {
   // set the light of this state
   document.getElementById('circle1').style.backgroundColor='black'
   document.getElementById('circle2').style.backgroundColor='black'
   document.getElementById('circle3').style.backgroundColor='green'

   // set a timeout of 1s, if it is over start the next function
   timer = window.setTimeout(trafficThree, 1000);
  }
  function trafficThree() {
   // set the light of this state
   document.getElementById('circle1').style.backgroundColor='black'
   document.getElementById('circle2').style.backgroundColor='yellow'
   document.getElementById('circle3').style.backgroundColor='black'

   // set a timeout of 1s, if it is over start the next function
   timer = window.setTimeout(trafficFour, 1000);
  }

  function trafficFour() {
   // set the light of this state
   document.getElementById('circle1').style.backgroundColor='red'
   document.getElementById('circle2').style.backgroundColor='black'
   document.getElementById('circle3').style.backgroundColor='black'

   // set a timeout of 1s, if it is over start the next function
   timer = window.setTimeout(trafficOne, 1000);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <button id ="change" onClick="toggle()" >Start traffic</button>
  <div id="container2">
   <div id="circle1"></div>
   <div id="circle2"></div>
   <div id="circle3"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain the toggle function in more detail? I understand the gist of it but not some parts. What does the if(timer) mean?

Comment: Add some comments, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your script, should help you hopefully:

```
<div id="container">
  <button id="change">Start traffic</button>
  <div id="container2">
    <div id="circle1"></div>
    <div id="circle2"></div>
    <div id="circle3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

...

```
var currentState = 0;
var trafficLights;

var setBgColor = function(id, color){
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = color;
};

function setTrafficLights(){
  switch(currentState){
    case 0: 
       setBgColor('circle1', 'red');
       setBgColor('circle2', 'yellow');
    break;
    case 1: 
       setBgColor('circle1', 'black');
       setBgColor('circle2', 'black');
       setBgColor('circle3', 'green');
    break;
    case 2: 
       setBgColor('circle1', 'black');
       setBgColor('circle2', 'yellow');
       setBgColor('circle3', 'black');
    break;
    case 3: 
       setBgColor('circle1', 'red');
       setBgColor('circle2', 'black');
       setBgColor('circle3', 'black');
    break;
  }
  currentState = (currentState + 1) % 4;
}

document.getElementById('change').addEventListener("click", function(){
  clearInterval(trafficLights);
  trafficLights = setInterval(setTrafficLights, 1000);
});
```